Is there a way to pass the prompt to Claude via the URL (i.e. URL parameter)?
ChatGPT can receive a prompt like so:
https://www.chatgpt.com/?q=capital%20of%20france%20

Is there a way to pass a prompt to Claude via the URL?
(this would be handy for integration with other tooling)

Havent used it, but the documentation provides an API, https://docs.anthropic.com/en/api/getting-started. Would that not suffice for integration?

@Zxeenu I'm using macOS's 'Alfred' which lets you do a google search by pressing command + space then typing g <search term>. I got it to give a chatgpt prompt by adding command + space then chat <prompt> and it works great (loads ChatGPT website wth the prompt already entered). Example: https://www.chatgpt.com/?q=capital%20of%20france%20 But I can't find a way to do it with claude, since I need to be able to put the promtp into a url. I guess I could use the APi  but it's less pretty and wouldn't allow me to easily follow up the conversation as a form in the regular web UI does

I just tested this. https://claude.ai/new?q={PLACE_HOLDER}, it works.
